# Data value not updated with tabs in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hi guys Im trying to make my custom tabs, with Vue js but Im having a problem since like my data property is not getting updated :(...
Here is the case Im having trouble with:
When I open 3 tabs, If I open my Modal on the first tab and then close that first tab, I will be switched to second tab but my Modal that was from first tab stays open like it is modal from the first tab instead of second... I would like each tab to have its own modal instance.

Here I posted bellow gif of what is happening. Basically I dont want my modal to apear again on next tab, when previous is closed :)

[image: My test case]

Seems like my data values, are not destroyed with first tab, and they are just replicated onto the second tab, Im trying to figure out what is the issue for few days now but no succes...

Here is my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="event-tabs wrapper">
            <div class="is-flex">
                <div class="tabs is-boxed control">
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="(newEvent, index) in newEventList" :key="index"  :class="selectedEventClass(index)"
                        @click.left="selectEvent(index)" @click.middle="discardEvent(index)">
                             <span class="event-tab-title">
                            TAB
                            </span>
                            <span class="event-tab-close" @click.stop="closeEvent(index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                         </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="add-tab">
                            <a @click.prevent="createEvent" :title="'Create Tab'">
                            <span>+</span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <tab v-for="(event, index) in newEventList" :event="event" :index="index"
                    v-if="showEventTab" v-show="index === selectedEvent" :key="index"
                    ref="eventTab"></tab>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import tab from './components/EventTab.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            tab,
        },
        computed: {
            newEventList() {
                return this.$store.getters['eventModule/getNewList'];
            },
            selectedEvent() {
                return this.$store.getters['eventModule/getSelectedNew'];
            },
            eventToEdit() {
                return this.$store.state.event.eventToEdit;
            },
            showEventTab() {
                return this.newEventList.length > 0;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            selectedEventClass(eventIndex) {
                return (eventIndex === this.selectedEvent) ? 'is-active' : '';
            },
            createEvent() {
                this.$store.dispatch('eventModule/create');
            },
            selectEvent(eventIndex) {
                this.$store.dispatch('eventModule/select', { eventIndex });
            },
            closeEvent(eventIndex) {
                this.$store.dispatch('eventModule/close', { eventIndex });
            },
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import './assets/scss/main';
</style>
```

My Tab component:

```
<template>
     <div class="event-form" v-if="event">

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-half">
            <div class="field">
                <h1>This is the TAB number {{ index}} </h1>
            </div>
            <p class="control">
                <button class="button is-danger" @click.prevent="openDialog">
                    Open Dialog
                </button>
            </p>
            <modalDialog  type="none" :show="modal.show"
                             :className="'eventTabModal'" :title="'Test modal'"
                             :text="'Test modal'"
                             @hide="closeDiscardModal">
                                <h3>Modal is active</h3>
                             </modalDialog>
         </div>                      
        </div>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    import modalDialog from './ModalDialog.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            modalDialog,
        },
        props: ['event', 'index'],
        data() {
            return {
                eventDefault: {},
                /**
                 *  Discard event modal
                 */
                modal: {
                    show: false,
                },
            };
        },
        computed: {
            eventList() {
                return this.$store.getters['event/getNewList'];
            },
            eventTypeList() {
                return this.$store.getters['eventType/getList'];
            },
        },
        methods: {
            /**
             * Opens discarded Modal
             */
            closeDiscardModal() {
                this.modal = {
                    show: false,
                };
            },
            openDialog() {
                this.modal = {
                    show: true,
                };
            },   
        },
    }
</script>
```

My Modal component for displaying Dialog:

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade">
        <div class="modal is-active" v-show="shouldShowModal" :class="className">
            <div class="modal-background" @click="hideModal"></div>
            <div class="modal-card">
                <header class="modal-card-head" v-if="title">
                    <p class="modal-card-title">{{ title }}</p>
                </header>
                <section class="modal-card-body">
                    <slot>
                        {{ text }}
                    </slot>
                </section>
                <footer class="modal-card-foot" v-if="type !== 'none'">
                    <template v-if="type === 'confirm'">
                        <a class="button is-success" @click.prevent="buttonClicked('yes')">Yes</a>
                        <a class="button is-danger" @click.prevent="buttonClicked('no')">No</a>
                    </template>
                    <template v-else-if="type === 'info'">
                        <a class="button" @click.prevent="buttonClicked('ok')">Ok</a>
                    </template>
                </footer>
            </div>
            <button class="modal-close is-large" @click="hideModal"></button>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            show: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
            title: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            type: {
                type: String,
                default: 'info',
            },
            className: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                shouldShowModal: this.show,
            };
        },
        watch: {
            show(newValue) {
                this.shouldShowModal = newValue;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            hideModal() {
                this.shouldShowModal = false;
                this.$emit('hide');
            },
            buttonClicked(type) {
                this.hideModal();
                this.$emit('buttonClicked', type);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

And My store module for Tabs:

```
const eventModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        /**
         * List of opened tabs
         */
        newList: [],
        selectedNew: 0,
        savedList: [],
        eventToEdit: null,
    },
    getters: {
        getNewList(state) {
            return state.newList;
        },
        getSelectedNew(state) {
            return state.selectedNew;
        },
        getSavedList(state) {
            return state.savedList;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        addNew(state, { location } = {}) {
            state.newList.push({
                typeId: null,
                active: true,
                logs: [],
            });
        },
        removeNew(state, index) {
            state.newList.splice(index, 1);
        },
        setNew(state, { index = state.selectedNew, event }) {
            state.newList.splice(index, 1, event);
        },
        selectNew(state, selectedNew) {
            state.selectedNew = selectedNew;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        /**
         * opens tab for creating new event
         *
         * @param context
         * @param location
         * @param stopProp
         * @returns {*}
         */
        create(context, { location, stopProp } = {}) {
            const newList = context.getters.getNewList;

            context.commit('addNew', { location });
            context.commit('selectNew', newList.length - 1);

            // if (!stopProp) {
            //     context.dispatch('stateChanged', null, { root: true });
            // }

            return Promise.resolve();
        },
        /**
         * Saves event
         * @param context
         * @param event
         * @return {Promise|Promise.<TResult>}
         */
        save(context, { event, index, hideMessage }) {
            const method = (event.id) ? 'patch' : 'post';
            // const data = { event, userId: context.rootGetters['user/getData'].id };
            const data = { event };
            const payload = { method, url: 'event', data, hideMessage };

            return context.dispatch('server/http', payload, { root: true })
                .then((response) => {
                    context.commit('setNew', { event: response.data.object, index });
                    context.dispatch('loadList');
                })
                .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
        },
        select(context, { eventIndex, stopProp }) {
            context.commit('selectNew', eventIndex);

        },
        opened(context) {
            const event = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context.state.eventToEdit));

            context.state.eventToEdit = null;
            context.dispatch('create', { stopProp: true });
            context.commit('setNew', { event });
        },
        /**
         * Closes for event
         * @param context
         * @param eventIndex
         * @param stopProp
         * @return {Promise|Promise.<TResult>}
         */
        close(context, { eventIndex, stopProp }) {
            const newList = context.getters.getNewList;
            const selectedNew = context.getters.getSelectedNew;

            context.commit('removeNew', eventIndex);

            if (selectedNew >= newList.length && selectedNew > 0) {
                context.commit('selectNew', selectedNew - 1);
            }
        },
    },
};

export default eventModule;
```

Also Here is the link to my github page where full test code is located if someone wants to take a look:

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxzmznm4w3)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It is advisable to include a minimal code example in your question instead of linking to vast 3rd party codebases. People (myself included) are more likely to help you if they do not need to dig for your code. :)

Comment: Yes I know, Im really sorry about that but code is maybe little big :( so I could post all of it here, will try to edit my question

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for ^^ It's just for your own good. Good! See if you can extract the "relevant" part of the code here. Or at least the essentials. Like the data object by instance.

Comment: Thanx for advice :), I extracted most important parts and edited my question.

Comment: Also, I do not fully understand the gif. You say the modal is precent on the other tabs. In your gif, it only seems that the modal is only on 1st tab and you do not switch tabs once its open. Am I mistaking?

Comment: Maybe you could explain your desired/expected result and your actual result a little better?

Comment: When I open 3 tabs, If I open my Modal on the first tab and then close that first tab, I will be switched to second tab but my Modal that was from first tab stays open like it is modal from the first tab instead of second... I would like each tab to have its specific modal instance :)

Comment: Why not prevent anything when a modal is open? What if the user decides to change tabs to a different tab? Does the context magically change?

Comment: how could I do that ? It changes when user change tab, I have this call this.$store.dispatch('eventModule/select', { eventIndex }); that changes it in store and v-show in App.vue that displays selected tab

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem is with keys in v-for,  :key prop, should be unique, so here is how I solved it,  in mutations addNew, add new property tabId add like this:

```
state.newList.push({
                tabId: new Date.now(),
                typeId: null,
                active: true,
                briefing: false,
                logs: [],
});
```

and App.vue change :key=“index” to :key=“event.tabId”